# Creating CCSprites and using them as a rope

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I have a tire in my screen and I would like to have a rope connected to the top of the tire and to the top of the screen. I have incorporated physics into my game with chipmunk+spaceManager so I need to some how have this rope react to the physics also. I just need it to move back and forth with the tire when it gets hit. I have used a cpConstraintNode to get a line drawn to use it as a rope up to this point but everything I have seen and looked into, there is no way to attach a CCSprite to a constraint. So my question is How would I go about creating this rope and have it react the same as the tire when it is moving? Here is my code that I have done with the constraint: I am using cocos2d and chipmunk + spaceManger

```
//The "rope"
        cpVect a1 = cpv(0,30);      //Local coordinates of tire
        cpVect a2 = cpv(70,320);    //World coordinates (staticBody is at (0,0))

        //calculate the length of the rope
        float max = cpvdist(cpBodyLocal2World(upper->body, a1), a2);
        cpConstraint *rope = [game.spaceManager addSlideToBody:upper->body fromBody:game.spaceManager.staticBody toBodyAnchor:a1 fromBodyAnchor:a2 minLength:1 maxLength:max];

        cpConstraintNode *ropeNode = [cpConstraintNode nodeWithConstraint:rope];
        ropeNode.color = ccBLUE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1112) presents a great way to draw ropes in Cocos2D using Verlet Integration.

The only drawback is that the example uses Box2D. But the code can be ported to chipmunk.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use the VRope project on github to integrate VRope and chipmunk, I've created a new branch that does just that. You'll find it at:

[VRope Chipmunk Branch](https://github.com/pkclsoft/VRope)

An example of using it is:

**Creation**

```
pinPointJoint = 
    cpSlideJointNew(body,
                    body2,
                    body.anchorPoint,
                    body2.anchorPoint,
                    minimumLength,
                    maximumLength);

cpSpaceAddConstraint(space, pinPointJoint);

rope = [[VRope alloc] init:pinPointJoint batchNode:ropeBatchNode];
```

**Updating**

```
[rope update:delta];
```